# Approximating Lebesgue integrable functions with continuous $2\pi$ periodic functions and trig polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f \in L_1[-\pi,\pi]$ and let $\epsilon > 0$.

1. Show that there exists a continuous $2\pi$ periodic function $g$ such that $\int_{[-\pi,\pi]}|f-g| < \epsilon$.
2. Show that there exists a trigonometric polynomial $T$ such that $\int_{[-\pi,\pi]}|f-T| < \epsilon$.

---

I am just a bit confused about the specifics for proving part 1. I have:

Given $\epsilon > 0$ and $f \in L_1[-\pi,\pi]$, $\exists h \in C[-\pi, \pi]$ such that $\int_{[-\pi,\pi]}|f-h| < \epsilon/2$.

What I have for the latter half of part 1 is what's confusing me. I think my details are worked out incorrectly but I'm not sure.

I want to define $g(x) = h(x) \forall x \in [-\pi,\pi)$ and $g(\pi) = g(-\pi)$. Then extend this to a $2\pi$ periodic function.

However, this means $g$ is not necessarily continuous (could be a discontinuity as we approach $g(\pi)$). So I actually need to define it a bit differently.

My next idea was to take: $g(x) = h(x) \forall x \in [-\pi,\pi-\epsilon/2]$, $g(\pi) = g(-\pi)$, and linear from $g(\pi-\epsilon/2)$ to $g(\pi)$ then extend this to a $2\pi$ periodic function. But then:

$\int_{[-\pi,\pi]}|g-h| = \int_{[\pi-\epsilon/2, \pi]}|g-h| \leq k*\epsilon/2$

where $|g-h| \leq k$ and $m([\pi-\epsilon/2, \pi]) = \epsilon/2$.

But obviously this is also not what I want. Can I instead define $g(x) = h(x)$ over the interval $[-\pi,\pi-\epsilon/2k]$ where k is as above (and then proceed similarly)?

And part 2 is easy once we have part 1 (since  continuous, $2\pi$-periodic functions can be uniformly approximated by trigonometric polynomials).

Comment: are you familiar with the abstract stone weirstrass theorem?

Comment: The Stone Weierstrass theorem we have seen in the course / textbook had to do with subalgebras of $C(X)$ where $X$ is a compact space. In particular, it said that if a subalgebra of $C(X)$ separates points and vanishes nowhere then it is dense in $C(X)$. I’m not sure if that’s what you meant by abstract Stone-Weierstrass?

Comment: ah ok good. It may be helpful to first approximate for $f\in L^1$, $f\cdot\mathbb{1}_{1/m,1-1/m}$ by continuous functions. You'll have to use dominated convergence at some point